# Imageview Background PNG Issue when set Wrap content

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I have a LayoutView in a ScrollView and want to set a my glass background PNG image that should be scaled automatically to wrap content.

In these layout view, there is a text view and the contents of this text area is variable.

Usually without any PNG background the size of layout view is not extended if isn't necessary to view all the text set, but when I set PNG background the layout view automatically enlarged to the size of the PNG if I set wrap content on layout view.

How to set a custom background image scalable to fit the size of layout view that doesn't influence the wrap content behavior?

Comment: can you add some screenshots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your requirement i would suggest you- take your background image of Height= approx 50 pixel width= any
- convert this image into nine patch follow this link- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/NinePatch.html

by using nine patch images your background will be re sized/adjust as per the dynamic data.

Hope it helps.
Thanks

Comment: Could you give me a sample to set a NinePatch as background of LayoutView?

Comment: converted nine patch image is same as normal png/jpg images. you dont need to know anything extra to set nine patch image as backgroung. Just convert normal image into nine patch image via that link and put it in your any drawable folder. IF u have successfully convert into nine patch than image name will be your_image_name.9. thanks

Answer (score 0):

## In my opinion, you have to:

- Set scaleType of Image view = "fitXY"
- Set layout_height, layout_width of layout = "wrap_content"

Comment: there isn't the option scaletype  fitXY for LayoutView.... is only in the image view